# Tabular with horizontal lines inside fancyhead

Tags: tables, fancyhdr

I have the following code for a fancyhead

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO,LE,LO,RE,RO]{} %% clear out all headers
\fancyhead[C]{%
          \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{7.5cm}|m{1.7cm}|m{3cm}|}
          \hline
          \vspace{1mm}
          \includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio=true]{./figures/albatroz_nobackground} &
          \centering
          \large{\textbf{PJN.2-ASLMS2014}}\\
          \vspace{3mm}
          \normalsize Albatroz Engenharia S.A. &
          \flushright
          Form:\\
          Project:\\
          Revision:\\
          Page:\\ &
          \flushleft
          ABZ.ENG(a)-1\\
          PJN.2-ASLMS2014\\
          Issue 1 Draft 1\\
          \thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}\\
          \tabularnewline
          \hline
          \end{tabular}%
}
```

It works perfectly but now I would like to add something like `\hline` or `\midrule` dividing some rows, for example, Form Project Revision, etc... but it always goes wrong with errors about misplaced `\noalign`. Does anybody have a clue of what is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable. `\flushright` and `\flushleft` are wrong there, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if this is the desired output.

Some notes:

- `\flushright` and `\flushleft` do not work with `\hline`, at least not this way and they shouldn't be used in a `tabular`. Use `\multicolumn{1}{l}{...}` and `\multicolumn{1}{r}{...}` for left or right justified cell content.
- Vertical lines in a `booktabs` tabular environment **do** look bad, since there is a vertical shift between the `|` and the horizontal lines, therefore I kept `\hline` instead of `\toprule` (or `\midrule` or `\bottomrule`)
- Vertical lines are most times bad, but in a more form-like table it's ok to use them.
- The 2nd column is too wide, I reduced the width
- `fancyhdr` complains about the head height, I increased this. Change the value appropiately.

Here is the `.tex` file.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}

\usepackage[tmargin=6cm,headheight=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead[C]{%
  \begin{tabular}{|m{3.0cm}|m{5.5cm}|m{1.7cm}|m{3cm}|}
    \hline
    \vspace{1mm}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,keepaspectratio=true]{./figures/albatroz_nobackground} &
    \centering
    \large{\textbf{PJN.2-ASLMS2014}}\\
    \vspace{3mm}
    \normalsize Albatroz Engenharia S.A. &
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Form:} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{ABZ.ENG(a)-1} \tabularnewline
    \hline
    & &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Project:} &   \multicolumn{1}{r|}{PJN.2-ASLMS2014}    \tabularnewline
    \hline
    & &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Revision:}&   \multicolumn{1}{r|}{Issue 1 Draft 1}\tabularnewline
    \hline
    & &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Page:} & \multicolumn{1}{r|}{\thepage \space of \pageref{LastPage}}\tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}%
}


\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\blindtext[20]
\end{document}
```

[image]